# How to get friends profile pics using FQL query using FBGraph-API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to know do I have an option to set pics width and height while requesting. Somebody suggested me to use the below query to achieve this behavior:

```
SELECT id, width, height, url, is_silhouette, real_width, real_height FROM profile_pic
 WHERE id=me() AND width=155 AND height=50
```

Is this the correct process? According to my requirement I need to display profile pics in a table as in the attached screenshot with 155 as width and 50 as height.

[image: My Friends List]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

FQL to get list of facebook friends information & their Pics

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT uid,name,first_name,last_name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (";
query = [query stringByAppendingFormat:@"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = %@)",userid];
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                query, @"query",
                                nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                       andParams: params
                   andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                     andDelegate:self];
```

You will get responce in follwing method

```
  -(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

For Example

```
{
    "first_name" =User;
    "last_name" = R;
    name = "User R";
    "pic_square" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/.jpg";
    uid = 595sd1;
     }
 {},{} etc
```

Hope this helps!

Another way is

Get the id (or the nick) of the user, and get the picture from https://graph.facebook.com/idOrNick/picture

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", id]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgView.image = image;
```

And for size

PICTURE SIZES:
square (50×50)

small  (50 pixels wide, variable height)

large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height)

and for applying this type of size you have to append it end of the URL

for example

http://graph.facebook.com/"id or Nick"/picture?type=large. [small/square/large]

Comment: femina : I am using FBGraphAPI, and what is the variable _facebook

Comment: I need to know how can i set its width and height

Comment: _facebook is object of Facebook Class.

Comment: For setting pics width and height while requesting......i have no idea.....but From above answer you can have image and then you can resize Image.

Comment: femina : i am using FBGraphAPI, so, i am not using facebook class, do we have any alternative for that ???

Comment: if you want to use Facebook class then use Hackbook for iOS. you will find all information on fb developer site.

Comment: there is another aprroch too....Get the id (or the nick) of the user, and get the picture from https://graph.facebook.com/idOrNick/picture

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", id]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; here id is User id.

Comment: @femina : i am trying this, can u say me where can i add the NSString *query = @"SELECT uid,name,first_name,last_name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (";
query = [query stringByAppendingFormat:@"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = %@)",userid];
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                query, @"query",
                                nil];

into which method.Can u help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code , which can help you to get friend's profile picture.

1. Get the Id of a friend from the FBGraph API e.g

   ```
    NSString *id = @"505326797";
   ```
2. Then paste the following code ...

   ```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",id]];
   ```
3. This is the way you can get the exact url of friend's picture ,, use this either in Asynchronous Image View or somewhere else.....

Perhaps it will help you...

Comment: I am getting the friends Profile picture, but i want to know how can i set the friends profile pic width and height

Comment: You can set the imageView width/Height , but your image will be stretched then....

Comment: thats why i would like to want without streching, we want to give the width and height previously

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your code is correct. This will get version of your picture that is approx. 155 x 50px.

If you wanted to get a user's friend's pictures, use [this query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20id%2C%20width%2C%20height%2C%20url%2C%20is_silhouette%2C%20real_width%2C%20real_height%20FROM%20profile_pic%0A%20WHERE%20id%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid1%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid2%3Dme())%20AND%20width%3D155%20AND%20height%3D50%0A):

```
 SELECT id, width, height, url, is_silhouette, real_width, real_height  
     FROM profile_pic
         WHERE id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) AND width=155 AND height=50
```

Comment: thank u for the answer, but i would like to know How can i send that Query to facebook, i am using FBGraphAPI, where i am not having requestWithMethodName, requestWithDelegate,

Answer (score 0):

Use the Graph API field expansion approach -

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=friends.fields(picture.height(50).width(155))
```

Comment: I have tried this way, when i am giving this way i am getting image width as 0.00 and height also 0.00

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the answer to this question, too. Finally I think this call is the best:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,picture.height(200).width(200)
```

You can also replace the 'me' with a certain id.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/ , there is a simpler way to do it. The direct URL to get customized image from facebook is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<USER_ID>/picture?width=<WIDTH>&height=<HEIGHT>
```

I understand the question is about using GraphAPI to get the URL but why make one extra call when you can give the image src URL directly.

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/${ID}/picture?width=${customwidth}&height=$customheight" />
```